Visual Studio 2022 Incorrect Error Squiggles related to WPF XAML Controls
For a good while now, VS 2022 has been displaying incorrect error squiggles in the code-behind .cs file for WPF controls anywhere that a FrameworkElement is referenced in the code. The code compiles and runs fine but it has become such a hindrance that I've had to disable the error squiggles altogether. I don't have any 3rd-party tools or such installed in Visual Studio - it's a simple setup. Has anyone experienced and found a solution to this? Deleting the .vs folder works only temporarily. I searched a lot and best/latest I could get is the issue registered with Microsoft below.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Incorrect-error-messages-in-xamlcs-fi/10595570?space=41&sort=newest

Sometimes I encounter this.
I solve it by deleting the bin and obj folders in Explorer. After a new build of the project, such errors disappear.

@EldHasp But that solution is only temporary? I have tried that, but the errors come back in some time.

The result is different. In some projects the error does not return, in others it may return and you have to do it again. Unfortunately, I still could not understand the reason for this problem and, accordingly, I do not know how to completely fix these errors.

There's a Vs extension adds an option  deletes bin and obj files. Or you could maybe write less code references specific controls.
